# two elements next to each other with 100% height of window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to put two elements next to each other but at least one of them (the textarea) I need to have always 100% height of the window. I've checked a few similar questions here but I don't know how to put that together. Could you help?

html:

```
<div style={styles.rowEqHeight}>
  <div style={styles.component}>
    <div className='input-group'>
      <textarea id='textarea'
                className='form-control'
                onChange={this.onDataChange}
                placeholder='Type your data...'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div style={styles.component}>
      <Treebeard data={this.state}
                 decorators={decorators}
                 onToggle={this.onToggle}/>
    </div>
```

styles.js

```
export default {
  component: {
    width: '50%',
    display: 'inline-block',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    padding: '20px',
  },
  rowEqHeight: {
    display: '-webkit-box',
    display: '-webkit-flex',
    display: '-ms-flexbox',
    display: 'flex'
  }
};
```

Comment: there's a css 100vh - means 100% of vertical height of the window, have u tried it?

Comment: No I haven't, tbh I am very new to that topic. Should I give it as a parameter for component height property? If so then it doesn't work. For some reason I cannot do anything with component height - whatever I put there it doesn't change anything.

Comment: It works. I just had to add it straight as a textarea height property not just div property. If you would like to write that as an answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using `100vh`  in your CSS or inline css for your element. That will set the height to 100% of the window .

sample below:

```html
<textarea style="height:100vh"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea id='textarea'
            className='form-control'
            onChange={this.onDataChange}
            placeholder='Type your data...'
            style="height: 100vh"></textarea>
```

This just demonstrates the styling. You could edit it to include the style in styles.js. The `vh` unit (abbreviated form of viewport height) is a percentage of the total height of the viewport, as evident from the name.